# OpenLDAP - Changing user password both locally and in LDAP

Tags: ldap, password, openldap

We have just implemented an LDAP solution for our lab. All of the LDAP client machines still have `files ldap` (or `files sss`) in their `nsswitch.conf` for the time being (so local authentication first), and a lot of the local accounts have already been transferred to LDAP directory.

Until we switch to authentication only through LDAP, is there any way that when a user changes their password it can be updated both on the LDAP server and locally (if the user has a local account)?

**Eg**: `user1` has a local account on `server1` and an account on LDAP. If `user1` runs `passwd`, is there any way to update the password both locally and on LDAP?

Thank you for any feedback!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that you are talking about Linux LDAP clients here.

I don't think that there is a native command to keep them in sync (you could write a script to sync periodically, but that can be messy and you would need to use the same one-way hashing mechanism).  What I would suggest doing is to build a wrapper script around the real `passwd` command and the `ldappasswd` command that takes the user's password from stdin (without `echo`'ing it) and then running the appropriate commands using the value that they provide.

You could even name the command `passwd` that is located earlier in `$PATH` or set up an alias that applies to all users' shell profile.